# Submitting two forms with javascript, one submits one not. Cant figure out why?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have this as Javascript code for my Ticket Model.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#submitForm').click(function(e) {
   $('#form1').submit();
   $('#form2').submit();
 });
});
```

On my ticket edit view, i have both ticket and its comments to update. Ticket form its named `form1` and comment form is named `form2`. If I only have `form1` on my javascript code, it updates perfectly, when I add `form2` only `form2` updates, so only the comment gets added, the Ticket Atributes (from `form1`) are not being updated.

Here is my Ticket View code (its actually a partial i'm loading on the edit view")

```
<%= form_for @ticket, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal', :id => 'form1' } do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :subject, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :subject, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :content, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_area :content, :class => 'text_area' ,:style => 'height:190px; width:655px', disabled: true %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label "Assigne", :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.collection_select(:user_id,  User.all, :id, :email) %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :department_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.collection_select(:department_id,  Department.all, :id, :name) %>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :status, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.select :status, options_for_select(["Open", "In Progress", "Waiting-for-Info", "Closed"]), :class => 'from-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :priority, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.select :priority, options_for_select([ "Normal", "High", "Immediate", "Low"]), :class => 'from-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :due_date, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.date_select :due_date, :class => 'date_select' %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
<h4>Comments</h4>
  <div id="comments">
    <%= render :partial => @ticket.comments %>
  </div>
    <%= form_for [@ticket, Comment.new], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal', :id => 'form2' }  do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.text_area :content, :class => 'text_area' ,:style => 'height:75px; width:600px' %></p></br>

    <% end %>
<%= submit_tag nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary', :id => 'submitForm' %>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When you submit one form, the page starts loading the form's "target". This means the second form can't "do" anything any more, since the browser's loading a new page.

Comment: I humbly suggest you need to accept SO answers to your questions.

Comment: You have several options. Using `$var data = ('#form1, #form2').serialize()` joining both and sending it up as a single action or you do an ajax request for each form to their required action, processing the responses manually (if there is any) by either binding to the individual submit events or just have a single button as a trigger. There is other ways of doing it but I would recommend to look into [**jQuery.ajax()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `$('#form1').submit();`, the page performs an http request. What this means is the page stops executing its javascript and begins performing the actions associated with said http request. (Usually this would be an http post to the form's target, where the data from the form is sent to the server.)

To bypass this, you need to look into ajax calls. An ajax call is an "*Asynchronous JavaScript and XML*" call, whereby you can perform http requests through your javascript code without interrupting anything else.

Ajax is a bit much to cover in an answer, so I will point you towards some [ajax documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX), and the [jQuery ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/). You might also want to glance at the [HTTP page on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) just to get a better understanding of how the web works.